# Laravel collective no reconoce la clase FORM laravel 5.3

Tags: php, html, laravel

Tengo instalado el `Laravel Collective` `HTML` para hacer los forms y todo lo que hace seguro a laravel.

Tengo puesto el `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,` en el config/app.php en el apartado de providers y tambien tengo puesto el

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

en el apartado de aliases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifica que instalaste la version correcta del paquete laravel collective, puedes verlo en tu composer.json

```
"laravelcollective/html":"^5.3.0"
```

En el archivo app.php, veo que has puesto asi:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class
```

Mientras que en tu titulo dice que no puede acceder con FORM, siendo que pusiste Form, verificalo, puede ser ese el problema